# Math riddle (ambiguous minutes/hours dials) - can you find my mistake?

Tags: puzzle

I was given the following riddle:

You are given a clock which has identical dials for the hours and minutes.
How many times a day you can't tell the time? (i.e. the dials are indistinguishable)?

**I'm not asking for a solution, but rather for help with my analysis.**

---

My first observation was that since the hours face completely determines the minutes dial, if $\alpha$ is the angle from 12 of the hours dial, $f(\alpha)$ is the angle of the minutes dial.

If $\alpha$ is measured in degrees, we can write $f$ as follows (each hour takes 30 degrees):

$$f(\alpha)=(\alpha \mod 30) \cdot 360$$

Two conditions has to hold so they may be confused:

1. $\alpha\neq f(\alpha)$. This has to hold since otherwise we know the hours dial and we're done.
2. $\alpha=f(f(\alpha))$. This is the condition that means we can't distinguish between the dials.

Writing (2) explicitly, assuming $\alpha$ is measured in degrees gives us:
$$\{*\} \alpha = [((\alpha \mod 30) \cdot 360)\mod 30]\cdot 360$$

Now we can use the following simple equality:
$$(x \cdot 360)\mod 30 =(x\mod \frac{1}{12})\cdot 360$$

Using it in $\{*\}$ we get:

$$ \alpha = ((\alpha \mod 30)\mod \frac{1}{12}) \cdot 360^2 = (\alpha \mod \frac{1}{12}) \cdot 360^2$$

But since $g(\alpha) = (\alpha \mod \frac{1}{12}) \cdot 360^2$  intersects $h(\alpha)=\alpha$ about $360\cdot 12$ times, it is tempting to say the answer for the question is $2 \cdot [ (360 \cdot 12) - 1]$ (where the (-1) is the 12 o'clock case).
This is clearly wrong as choosing to measure $\alpha$ in degrees is arbitrary, and measuring it differently would yield different result.

> But where is the mistake in the process?

Comment: Perhaps by "dial" you mean "hand". The *dial* is the fixed face of the clock, with the numbers marked on it, around which the hour-hand and minute-hand move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $f(\alpha)=(\alpha \bmod 30)\cdot 12$ because, when $\alpha$ increases by $30$, the angle of the minute hand increases by $30\cdot 12$

Comment: Yep, its as foolish as that, thanks !

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make.